# ps command cpu utilization for gunicorn always reads 0%

Tags: linux, django, postgresql, gunicorn

I am charting my CPU/MEM usage for some gunicorn workers I have running with multiple django apps and I am getting the info from the `ps` command

I am running this...

```
/bin/ps -C gunicorn -o pcpu -o pmem -o cmd
```

which always outputs like this:

```
%CPU %MEM CMD
 0.0  0.5 command
 0.0  0.5 command
 0.0  2.2 command
 0.0  0.6 command
 0.0  0.7 command
 0.0  0.7 command
```

which is great but the CPU% is always at 0...even if I make my app do some CPU heavy process like pulling A LOT of info out of a postgresql database.

Shouldn't the CPU% be going up when the gunicorn worker is told to do something like that?

Comment: Pulling a lot of info out of PostgreSQL mostly creates load on the PostgreSQL side, not on the client side -- it's almost all wait there -- so the load is mostly allocated to the server, unless you're doing something expensive with the data you receive. Anyhow, I'd suggest looking at what *does* get the load, and also using tools more sensitive than `ps` (a good `top` variant like `htop` will actually do a better job just because it's watching over a long enough period of time to be able to get accounting data to compare between multiple refreshes spaced at least a second or so apart).

Comment: On a different note -- `ps` is not part of bash, so the bash tag does not belong on this question. You'd have the exact same behavior from ash, dash, zsh; calling `ps` direct from Python or Ruby or Java or C without any shell at all involved; etc.